# Difference between a selected node and its imported node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the below code, I commented A and B at each lines.
What is the different between A and B? And which is recommended?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<template id="templatetest">
    <div>test</div>
</template>

<body></body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = document.querySelector('#templatetest');

    var n = document.importNode(t.content, true);
    document.body.appendChild(n); //A

    document.body.appendChild(t.content); //B
</script>

</html>
```

And one more question..
The above code renders two "test"s. But when I switch positions of A and B like the below code, only one "test" is rendered somehow.
 I would like to know why this happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = document.querySelector('#templatetest');

    document.body.appendChild(t.content); //B

    var n = document.importNode(t.content, true);
    document.body.appendChild(n); //A
</script>
```

Comment: Check the docs for boths methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Comment: Actually, I've read them many times, and still don't know which one  is better. If I understand right, the node of A is a copy of the template, and the node of B is a reference of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points is `importNode` creates a copy of the node and returns it, then you can add it in a new parent using `appendChild`. It's intended to be used when you're getting nodes from anoother documents and inserting it in your doc (for example, when you're moving nodes between different XML files), this function will fix things like the ownerDocument property and other internal things I believe.

The `appendChild` just to append nodes to other nodes, if the node you is appending is already a child of any other node, first it will remove it from there and move it to its new parent.

In your first example:

- A - you create a copy of t.content (n - `importNode`) and append it to the body;
- B - you just append t.content to body, thus removing it from it's original parent

Your second example

- B - You moves the content of #templatetest to the body
- A - #templatetest is now empty, it has no more content, so there is nothing to you copy and append in your body anymore

Comment: ugh!! t.content should not be empty! Thank you so much. I should have read the doc of appendChild once more carefully.